# Notify from an Exec only if the exec was succesfull

Tags: puppet

I am currently learning puppet, and I am attempting to have an `exec` that will notify another exec but only if the first exec is succsfull. However currently I am struggling to figure out how to do this. Right now I have:

```
  exec { 'first command':
    command => "some command"
    path => '/usr/bin',
    notify  => Exec["second command"],
  }

  exec { 'second command':
    command => "run another command if first command was succesfull",
    path    => '/usr/bin',
    refreshonly => true,
  }
```

How can this be modified so that the second command is only run if the first command is successful as currently it is run no matter what after the first command?

Comment: At the moment, that pattern works to run the second command only if the first command _is also run_. Just to clarify, is that definitely not what you want?

Comment: Are you sure, @Alex?  In addition to sending an event, `notify` has the semantics of `before`.  To the best of my knowledge, then, if the first Exec fails, the second should neither be applied nor refreshed.

Comment: Yes but the OP also has "refreshonly" => true unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I think you *are* missing something: a resource that fails does not send events.

Comment: I guess by "is also run" I meant "is also _successfully_ run".

Comment: Ok, @AlexHarvey, I think we're on the same page.  I thought you were saying that the OP's code should have behavior different from he seems to be saying he wants.  In fact, the code presented should *already* have the behavior the OP seems to be asking for, so I think we're both uncertain about what he's really asking.

Comment: This question would greatly benefit from a [mcve] to clarify it.  The fake code presented within is certainly small, but it is not runnable and therefore not verifiable.  I am furthermore inclined to doubt that merely providing genuine `command` parameters could cause application of the two resources alone to produce behavior different from what the OP says he wants.